# Why do RxJS pipe subscribe callbacks sometimes not fire?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm sure this is a design issue on my part, but I'm trying to understand why RxJS pipe.subscribe callbacks do not fire. In the code below, `next`, `error`, and `complete` callbacks do not fire. What needs to change to make that happen?

In this case, the polling of the endpoint works just fine but the .subscribe callbacks never get called.

```
this.service
      .postThing('/endpoint', {params})
      .then((response.id) => {
        interval(3000)
          .pipe(
            switchMap(() => this.service.getThing('/endpoint', response.id)),
            retryWhen((errors) =>
              errors.pipe(filter((err) => err.status === 404))
            )
          )
          .subscribe(
            (data) => {
              console.log(data);
            },
            (error) => {
              console.log(error)
            },
            () => {
              this.service.stopLoading()
            }
          );
      });
```

Comment: try change switchMap to mergeMap

Comment: are you sure you can have `response.id` as parameter name for the function passed to `then`?

Answer (score 0):

## Toward a Solution

There are a few things I noticed.

1. What is `params`? Right now you're creating an object with a String key "params" that has whatever `params` evaluates to.

```hs
{
  params: params
}
```

2. You cannot have variable names with `.` in them. `service.id` is not a valid name. If you meant to destructure `service`, you could write `{id}`.
3. Interop between promises and observables is fairly seamless, even so, I wouldn't recommend mixing the two styles of asynchronous programming unless it's necessary. If you're already using observables, then just stick with those.
4. Your error handling filters out errors, which means your program will just stall (the observable never completes). That's probably not what you're after. You can pass forward errors with `throwError(err)` or complete by using `EMPTY`

### Implemented

You can write something like this:

```hs
from(
  this.service.postThing('/endpoint', {params})
).pipe(
  mergeMap(response => interval(3000).pipe(
    mapTo(response)
  )),
  switchMap(response => 
    this.service.getThing('/endpoint', response.id)
  ),
  retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(
    mergeMap(err => err.status === 404 ? 
      of(err) :       // Retry on 404, otherwise
      throwError(err) // finish with error
    )
  ))
).subscribe({
  next: console.log,
  error: console.log,
  complete: () => this.service.stopLoading()
});
```

### Final thoughts

This may or may not solve your problem. There's only so much we can guess from a code sample like this. Even so, this structure should be a bit easier to debug. You can use `tap(console.log)` within a pipe to see the value at any given part.